# Get children with unknown keys in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a blog posting app. I need to display the posts with the name of the author and the time.
I'm adding the post to database at `posts/uid/key` This key is added by Firebase on pushing the values. I cannot set this key to a fixed value as each post has different name, time, and body. 
Now while retrieving the data, I want to know how to get the data at `posts/uid/key/`
I'm using this loop to traverse all the children of `posts/` But I cannot go further into the nesting as I don't know what the keys are

[image]

```
 for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String uid = (String) postSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
                    String body = (String) postSnapshot.child("body").getValue();


                }
            }
```

I'm attaching the above listener to this reference 

`mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");`

How do I get the children of the keys without getting what the keys are?

---

```
private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("posts");

    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String uid = (String) postSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
                String body = (String) postSnapshot.child("body").getValue();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), body,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
        }
```

---

Exported JSON

```
  {
  "posts" : {
    "-KTGou5X14D8pq1sxyhR" : {
      "body" : "first post",
      "timestamp" : 1475620339666,
      "uid" : "tmFt3NbcnLVlkrWQrIx1"
    },
    "-KTGp3mfM4krbGoTMZ8t" : {
      "body" : "second post",
      "likeCount" : 0,
      "uid" : "tmFt3NbiwLVlkrWQrIx1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by can't go further in nesting ? I can't see any more nest. **Please post the relevant actual json of your firebase database.**

Comment: By further nesting I meant that I can't go from posts/ to the next nesting level. I've depicted the unknown key here as text. I don't know what this key is so I can't get body and timestamp.

Comment: Please post exported json from firebase as requested in my previous comment.

Comment: Add the code that shows how you get the DataSnapshot, including the DatabaseReference that shows the location in your JSON tree that you start loading from.

Comment: Are you saving the data anywhere ? I don't think it will persist unless you save it somewhere. Maybe that's why you feel you getting result of just one key. ValueEventListener should get you all changed data in shapshot am not sure about your nesting issue. Did you try logging your datasnapshot ? It should give you better idea about the data you receiving from firebase.

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. I want to fetch all the children, one by one. How do I do that?

Comment: And by children i mean i want to fetch all the "body" and "uid", Even if I don't know what the pushed key is

Comment: I understand your problem and looking at your code I can only suggest you one thing which is go through this :https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data                 and also this : https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html                                                                                                             and then try again!

Comment: Hi Nishant can you email me at mish.shubh@gmail.com, I need your help with firebase. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to please wait for a reply from **senior Firebase engineer - Frank van Puffelen** He might guide you better in case I missed something.